# iOS change rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller

I have 3 viewControllers named firstController, secondController and thirdController.
 My logic is firstController.presentViewController(secondController), then secondController.presentViewController(thirdController), and the set a rootViewController by UIApplication.shareApplication().keywindow!.rootViewController = firstController...

But when I set firstController as the rootViewController, when presenting viewController from secondController to thirdController with thirdController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve, the firstController will show during the animate.

May I should not use the rootViewController like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have one level rootViewController presenting everything, i.e., only firstController should be calling presentViewController.

Comment: Thanks for your commenting, but both secondController and thirdController have a button to dismiss themselves.